# Why doesn't inline-grid work in Safari?

Tags: html, css, browser, safari, inline

I am working on a WordPress gravity form and used inline-grid for the layout. 
It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome.

But when it comes to Safari, `display: inline-grid` does not work. 
Although `display: inline-block` works.

---

**Run the following code snippet in Safari to see what I am talking about.**

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-grid;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<hr>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
```

Comment: I confirm that the lower blocks are one-atop the other in safari, whereas they are side-by-side in chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari supports CSS Grid Layout

```
desktop -- from version 10.1
ios -- from version 10.3
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Probably you're using not a very fresh Safari.

BTW, on my desktop v. 10.1.1 your code works as expected.

Comment: That was it. I tried again on another Mac with Sierra and it worked just fine. I have El Capitan. By "not very fresh" you mean the version right before the current latest version? Haha. Anyways, thanks Kosh!