# display:inline-grid doesn't support on very fresh safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

In my website i designed a `ul` which displays social icons in my page.

structure

```
<ul>
  <li>icon1</li>
  <li>icon2</li>
  <li>icon3</li>
  <li>icon4</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul{
   list-style-type: none;
}
ul>li{
  display: inline-grid;
}
```

The above css works in all the css except **non fresh safari browsers**.I found this issue while checking on **OPPO** mobiles. They are using non fresh safari.

[Screenshot from IOS safari browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYcuU.png)

[Screenshot from OPPO browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2h78.jpg)

There is a same kind of question in stackoverflow here ([Why doesn't inline-grid work in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659311/why-doesnt-inline-grid-work-in-safari)). But there I couldn't find a proper alternative answer for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the safari does not support `inline-grid;`

The supporting is only from:https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

```
safai: version 11.1 + 
safari ios: from version 10.3 +
```

You can use `display: inline-block;` instead `inline-grid;`

```css
ul{
   list-style-type: none; 
}
ul>li{
     display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>icon1</li>
  <li>icon2</li>
  <li>icon3</li>
  <li>icon4</li>
</ul>
```

**Note!** 
the is another way use `flex` but as I see it does not support old safari

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox instead of grid. Support for old Safari (from version 7 with prefix) is: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

```css
ul{
   display: flex;
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>icon1</li>
  <li>icon2</li>
  <li>icon3</li>
  <li>icon4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `flex` does not support from old safari

Comment: @לבנימלכה full support from version 7 with prefix.

Comment: so attach it to your answer

Comment: It didn't work. Flex is a real new attribute and it still have issues in browser comfortability.